# Server-side EntityErrors for ComplexType objects

Tags: javascript, breeze

I have a project that uses *AngularJS* and *BreezeJS*. I'm using the *zValidate* directive to display property validation errors. I forked the directive so it shows client side errors on complex type fields as well. Now I have a problem with the server-side errors.

I can't get the server-side errors to show up with zValidate, **if** the field is part of a **complex type object**.

After the data passes the client validation it is sent to the backend and saved using a custom web service. This web service sends back information which field failed.
Right now I'm creating EntityError instances in the following way.

```
Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityError error = new Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityError();
error.ErrorMessage = returnData.Message;
error.ErrorName = "Attribute Validation Error";
error.EntityTypeName = personType.FullName;
error.PropertyName = prop.Name;
error.KeyValues = new object[] { returnData.id };
List<Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityError> errors = new List<Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityError>() { error };

throw new Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityErrorsException(errorText, errors);
```

personType is the type of my model class and prop.Name is the name of the erroneous property (eg. FirstName).

I believe the problem is related to what the PropetyName (and EntityTypeName?) should be.